# Looking for a database of minimal pairs

Tags: english, phonology, reference-request, minimal-pairs

I'm looking for a database of english minimal pairs that is at least somewhat organized by some principle such as features or phonemes similar to : 
https://www.speech-language-therapy.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=125:wordlists&catid=9:resources&Itemid=108
http://www.minpairs.talktalk.net/minimal.html

These are fine, but I would need to write a web scraper to parse through all the data. Is there any publicly available minimal data in a more accessible format like a .csv?

Comment: yes, updated to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future people who may need this, I ended up writing a webscraper and compiling everything from www.minpairs.talktalk.net. You can view/download the corpus here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSdkp5omzWF0-Tfq2VJH9c5UWnj7BVJN7BBssWDFqNQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I take it this is the product of slurping in those data, and it wasn't evaluated for further minimal-pairness. E.g. antique [æ̀ntʰɪ́k] vs. antic [ǽntɪk] isn't minimal, there are 3 differences. Maybe it depends on your definition of minimal pair (which is...?). Dialect disclaimers also (beta and bitter).

Comment: That's right, and I believe that database is for RP English. There's also a few weird entries (like just "s"). It also does not include inflectional variation of the root word. It's still useful for what I need in this form but use with caution!